# How to activate environments in anaconda by default?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3, anaconda-cluster

Everytime when I want to create an environment using Anaconda Navigator, the 'create' button is greyed out as shown in figure.
So using Anaconda prompt, I created the environment using the below commands.

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

[image]

Everytime I open Anaconda-navigator, these newly created environments are greying out and I need to activate this manually through command prompt.
For example, before opening anaconda-navigator, I had to manually activate myenv tensorflow. Is spite of this, even the buttons are disabled.  Is there a default setting to set such that these environments are already activated? Also, why are these buttons 'create,clone,delete' greyed out?

Answer (score 1):

Try closing Navigator, opening a terminal in your base environment and updating Navigator

conda update anaconda-navigator

That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution didn't work for me. I had to disconnect VPN, and then in the terminal, I had to create a new environment, and add the packages inside this environment.